# Generate string value by loop in another column based on the specified range of dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm dealing with customers applications data and what I want is to group these applications in batches according to range of dates where the applications is created.

```
SELECT 
  applications.customer_id, 
  applications.Created_at,
  CASE
    WHEN ((applications.created_at) BETWEEN '2017-07-17T00:00:00' AND '2017-07-20T23-59-59') THEN 'Batch 1'
    WHEN ((applications.created_at) BETWEEN '2017-07-21T00:00:00' AND '2017-07-24T23-59-59') THEN 'Batch 2'
    WHEN ((applications.created_at) BETWEEN '2017-07-25T00:00:00' AND '2017-07-27T23-59-59') THEN 'Batch 3'
    WHEN ((applications.created_at) BETWEEN '2017-07-28T00:00:00' AND '2017-07-31T23-59-59') THEN 'Batch 4'
    ELSE 'unknown'
  END AS Batch
```

basically every

> tuesday of the week@ 00:00:00  to thursday 23:59:59

is one batch, and

> friday 00:00:00 to monday 23:59:59 is another.

in short we want to group this applications in 2 batches every week and 8 batches per month.

> example: Jan-Batch1..,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 ||| Feb-Batch1..,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 and so
> on

The above query is fine for a month, but for a year I would have write 100 lines of queries and is not Ideal. I would like to have a loop to generate the strings

FYI I use this to visualize the data in superset and currently I only have a read-only access to the database.

How the table should look:

[image: how the table should look like]

Answer (score 0):

You could create a calendar table which hard codes all the start/end timestamp pairs which you want to examine in your query.  The table would look something like this:

```
table: intervals
start                 | end
'2017-07-17T00:00:00' | '2017-07-20T23-59-59'
'2017-07-21T00:00:00' | '2017-07-24T23-59-59'
'2017-07-25T00:00:00' | '2017-07-27T23-59-59'
'2017-07-28T00:00:00' | '2017-07-31T23-59-59'

SELECT
    t1.start,
    t1.end,
    COUNT(t2.customer_id) AS num_applications
FROM intervals t1
LEFT JOIN applications t2
    ON t2.created_at BETWEEN t1.start AND t1.end
GROUP BY t1.start, t1.end
```

This would give you each range along with a count of how many customers opened applications in that range.

Comment: For regular intervals, this approach seems rather unnecessary

Comment: +1 for the answer but the hard-coded approach is not scalable, the data is updated everyday. I want it to be automated where it increments the batch numbers and the months from the given start date. I have added an example of my query result on the question.

Comment: @HusenMuhammadB Then you might want to consider using dynamic SQL here.  Build the hard coded query using simple logic.

Comment: any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is above my paygrade.  Someone else will give you code.

Comment: I think I asked for a guidance not a code, I want to learn how to query better.